# Sharepoint 2010 Subsite/Document Library/Lists Storage Data

Tags: sharepoint-2010, storage, document-library, sharepoint-list

Basically all I want to do is to get the *total* storage space of subsites, document libraries and lists within a site collection. There does not seem to be a possible way to do it besides:

1. using `site.StorageManagementInformation` which is currently Obsolete
2. `SPSite.UsageInfo` this can only work for site collection:

   ```
   SPSite.UsageInfo usageInfo = spSite.Usage;
   long storageUsed = usageInfo.Storage;
   ```
3. `SPWeb.GetUsageData` which only gets the current day(and up to the last 31 days) usage data.
4. finding the database table where Site Collection Administration > Storage Metrics is querying from (which I could not find even with using a .NET Reflector for the assembly)

If anyone has any other way or idea on how to achieve this it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to try opening the site you are accessing via SharePoint Designer and right click any those collections then click properties. The size of the objects should be shown there as well. :)